# Can Pandoc output syntax-highlighted codeblocks from a vimwiki source?

Tags: pandoc, vim-plugin

For markdown Pandoc's syntax highlighting works great, for example for a file
`test.md` that looks like this

````
some text...

```sh
for i in {1,2,3}; do echo ${i}; done
```
````

the command 
`pandoc -f markdown -t html -s --highlight-style=zenburn -o out.html test.md`
generates html-output `out.html` that basically has the syntax highlighting
specified in `zenburn` "baked in" and a browser renders it as you'd want:

[image: screenshot of markdown-generated html in browser]

However for the vimwiki-format (which pandoc supports) this doesn't seem to
work even though I haven't found anything saying the syntax highlighting was
limited only to some source formats.

**Basically:** Can I get pandoc to do the same style of syntax highlighting in the
html output if my source format is `vimwiki` and my source looks like this:

```
some text...

{{{sh
for i in {1,2,3}; do echo ${i}; done
}}}
```

because doing 
`pandoc -f vimwiki -t html -s --highlight-style=zenburn -o out.html test.wiki`
yields (what you can also tell from the generated html) this:

[image: screenshot of vimwiki-generated html in browser]

Comment: Seems to work for me. Which pandoc version are you using?

Comment: `pandoc --version` states `pandoc 2.9.2.1 Compiled with pandoc-types 1.20, texmath 0.12.0.2, skylighting 0.8.4`.
Could you tell me your version? maybe I'll just set something up in docker if I know it works on a specific version.

Comment: whoops, my bad: I was trying with a development version. Which means that the good news is that this is fixed. If you are comfortable with docker, then you should probably try the pandoc/core:edge image.

Comment: Just confirmed that this works as desired: `docker run --rm --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD":/data pandoc/core:edge -f vimwiki -t html -s --highlight-style=zenburn -o out.html test.wiki`.

Comment: That's very good to know, thanks.